# regex to match specific html tags

Tags: .net, regex

I need to match html tags(the whole tag), based on the tag name.

For script tags I have this:

```
<script.+src=.+(\.js|\.axd).+(</script>|>)
```

It correctly matches both tags in the following html:

```
<script src="Scripts/JScript1.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/JScript2.js" />
```

However, when I do link tags with the following:

```
<link.+href=.+(\.css).+(</link>|>)
```

It matches all of this at once(eg it returns one match containing both items):

```
<link href="Stylesheets/StyleSheet1.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Stylesheets/StyleSheet2.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

What am I missing here?  The regexes are essentially identical except for the text to match to?

Also, I know that regex is not a great tool for HTML parsing...I will probably end up using the HtmlAgilityPack in the end, but this is driving me nuts and I want an answer if only for my own mental health!

Comment: If this is driving you nuts, why aren't you using the HTML Agility Pack yet then?

Comment: I'm downloading it right now...I just can't figure out why those won't match!

Comment: Your REs are ambiguous due to overuse of `.` In Python, both REs match the entire input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .+ wildcards match anything. This:

```
<link.+href=.+(\.css).+(</link>|>)
```

Likely matches like this:

```
<link      => <link
.+         => href="Stylesheets/StyleSheet1.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
              <link 
 href=     => href=
 .+        => "Stylesheets/StyleSheet2
 \.css     => .css
 .+        => " rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" /
 </link>|> => >
```

Instead consider using [^>]+ in place of .+. Also, do you really care about the closing  tag?

```
<link[^>]+href=[^>]+(\.css)[^>]+>
```

Comment: +1 good explanation and for pointing out the negative character class `[^>]+` approach.

Comment: The `>` is allowed in an attribute value.

Comment: `>` is allowed in attributes and that will break this solution. It's an unlikely problem for a link tag, which is fortunate because this will not be easily remedied in a regexp. The OP's solution of using HtmlAgilityPack is ultimately the correct one.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, still not totally sure why my original worked for script tags though, oh well.  Although I'm now about 75% done refactoring w/ the Agility Pack... And just to answer your question, the application needs to grab the whole tag, including the closing tag if it's there.

Comment: Looking again at your problem statement, I too am perplexed. These regexps are congruent and should produce similar results. Is it possible that in your test the link tags share a common line, while the script tags have a newline between them?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your regex is greedy. Whenever you match `.+` this is greedy; you need to make it non-greedy by appending a `?` to them which makes it match a limited number of characters to satisfy the pattern and not go beyond it to the next matching string.

Change the pattern to this: `"<link.+?href=.+?(\.css).+?(</link>|>)"`

Then you'll need to use `Regex.Matches` to get multiple matches and loop over them.